# Is mutable ID safe with Hibernate and Ehcache?

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache

Is it safe to use a mutable ID with Hibernate and Ehcache? Also note that `hashCode` is based on the ID.

```
class Company implements Serializable {
  String code; // PK
  public int hashCode() {
    return code == null ? 17 : code.hashCode();
  }
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    // Some obvious equals checking for type and field equality
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between *business key* and *surrogate key* concepts. Usually, ID means an immutable identifier (surrogate key), which has no business meaning. At the database level a corresponding column would be a primary key, so that it could be referenced by foreign keys in other tables to ensure referential integrity. Entity properties that model ID are often of type Long.
Its value is assigned once and never changed.

The business key could consists of one or more entity properties (and thus columns), which can be mutable.

The provided in the question snippet suggests that field `code` (should be private) is a business key. So, it can be changed as required. Although the entity type is missing an ID field.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably not a good idea.  (It suggests that you intend to use a business key (the code) as the primary key for the object.  This can lead to complications if your processes require you to be able to change or reassign the key.)

However, whether it is safe or not (in the Hibernate case at least) depends on how and then the "code" field is mutated.  If you change the code for an object after it has been made persistent, you will break the relationship between the copies in memory and in the database, and bad things will happen.

Another concern is that if the "code" field changes while the object is in a `HashMap` or `HashSet`, then the object or the entry is likely to be lost.